# Difference in Django object creation call

Tags: django-models, oop

I'd like to know if there's a difference between the following two calls to create an object in Django

```
Animal.objects.create(name="cat", sound="meow")
```

and

```
Animal(name="cat", sound="meow")
```

I see both in test cases and I want to make sure I am not missing something.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The former also inserts a row in the database as well as creating the object.

Comment: you mean it saves it right away, while I have to do it manually with the second one right ?